# JavaFX GUI stuck

Tags: user-interface, service, javafx

I'm new here and I'm new to Java programming but I had to sign up only to ask you this cause it bothers me for days.
Anyway, I am writing TCP Client. I made two threads: one for reading from System.in and sending to socket, and other one for reading from socket and writing to System.out.
That worked fine but now I need to make a GUI and I know that I need to use Task and/or Service if I want to keep my GUI interactive, but I don't know how to make my threads as Service.
Here's code (that worked in terminal):

```
public static class ReadThread extends Thread
{
    BufferedReader in;
    String word;

    ReadThread(BufferedReader in)
    {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            while((word = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(word);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Similar to this, I made WriteThread but I don't want to make this post messy so...
Anyway, when I tried to implement this as a Service, I had to make "in" a final which generated some other errors and so on and so on.
I'd appreciate if you'd help me on my particular case cause I probably read all the JavaFX GUI problems on this site haha
Thanks in advance and sorry for a long post! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I implement service

```
public class ReadService extends Service {

    BufferedReader in;
    String word;

    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        return new Task() {
            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    while((word = in.readLine()) != null)
                        System.out.println(word);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    public BufferedReader getIn() {
        return in;
    }

    public void setIn(BufferedReader in) {
        this.in = in;
    }
}
```

And where you have to call your service.

```
 ReadService readService = new ReadService();
         readService.setIn(//HEre your in);
          readService.restart();
```

You can also add some handler when your service start, cancel, failed, finish ...

```
  readService.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(WorkerStateEvent workerStateEvent) {
          // Here the finish action
      }
  });
```

That it

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! But now I have to get and set from textField and textArea instead of System.in and System.out.
I actually made it work reading from System.in and writing to textArea, but I don't know how to get text from textField. I don't want to use Send button all the time, and I don't know how to send an event method to Service class.
Any ideas?

Comment: In a TextField or TextArea, you can add an eventListener on the textProperty() of your textfield and it will call when the text changed. Or you can just to textfield.getText()

Comment: But should I .start() new writeService Task with every new event on text changed or can I somehow pass a method to writeService?
Sorry but I find it very confusing cause of the variables scope :(
What confuse me the most are these two lines:
` while((command = in.readLine()) != null)
 out.println(naredba); ` . I can't write command = textField.getText(); cause it won't know when to get the text.
Sorry for being pain in the neck but I need to get this done :D

Comment: When did you need to get the text exactly ? just befor launch your service you set in the service a string variable for exemple with the textfield value, and in your service you can use this string variable

Comment: Yes, but that string should change all the time. I'm building interactive UNIX shell, so in textField I write shell command, send it to unix server, and result print in textArea. Did you mean maybe that I make an event handler and with every triggered event, send a string value to writeService?

Comment: if you need to call the service all time the textfield change, I think you don't have choice to do something like that : add a changeListener to your textProperty() of your textfield, inside this event, set the string in the service and call service.restart() . for what you need im not sure there is a better solution
And for information, when you call restart, all the variable members stay the same until you set it.