# JavaFX stop threads

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, javafx

I write a program which needs to receive informations from a server. I use asynchronous threads to accomplish that. But when the user clicks on another item a new thread gets launched. If the first one has not yet finished for example because of a network issue, the second thread ends and sets the UI information. Then the first one ends and overwrites it again. So how can I stop the first thread when the user clicks on another item?

I got that:

```
Thread asyncThread = new Thread(task);
asyncThread.start();
```

But from what I can see in the Thread object, there is no way to stop the thread (only deprecated .stop()), but I don't want to use deprecated stuff for new programs.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaFX it's recommended to use Service, a service provides method like, stop(), cancel(), restart()... Look my answer to this [JavaFX GUI stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246099/javafx-gui-stuck/17250127#17250127) to show how use Service.